# Unable to pass email address to Perl script using command line

Tags: perl

I am trying to pass two email addresses to MySQL to find their accounts. I call my script like this:

```
./message-2.pl  user1@s  'rech user2@s 22'
```

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use DBI;
use IO::Handle;

our $calerid = "'$ARGV[0]'";
our $message = "$ARGV[1]";
our $msg_arg1 = qx(echo $message | awk '{print \$1}');
our $msg_arg2 = qx(echo $message | awk '{print \$2}');
my $share_reciver =  "'$msg_arg2'";

my $database = "mya2billing";
my $host = "localhost";
my $port = "3306";
my $user = "root";
my $pass = "xxxxxx";
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=$database;host=$host;port=$port";
my $sth;

# find card id
my $query1 = "SELECT  id_cc_card FROM cc_callerid WHERE cid = $calerid ;";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pass) || die "Could not connect to database:$DBI::errstr";
our $card;
print " query=$query1\n";

if (!($sth = $dbh->prepare($query1))) {
    die ("Failed to prepare statement: " . DBI->errstr);
}                           
$sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
my @result;  
while (@result = $sth->fetchrow_array) { # retrieve one row
    ($card) = @result;
    print "card id found: $card \n";
}   

if ($msg_arg1 =~ "rech" or $msg_arg1 =~ "Rech"  or $msg_arg1 =~ "bal" or $msg_arg1 =~ "Bal") {
    recharge();
}   

sub recharge {
    print " we are in rech section\n";
    our $msg_arg2 = qx(echo $message | awk '{print \$2}');
    our $share_reciver="$msg_arg2";


    my $query2 = "SELECT id_cc_card FROM cc_callerid WHERE cid = '$share_reciver' ";
    my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pass);
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($query2);
    $sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;

    print " query=$query2\n";
    my $receiver_id;

    while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
        ($receiver_id) = @row;
        print " we are in query section\n";
        print "receiver_cardid:$receiver_id \n";
    }

    exit 1;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
[root@laptop Desktop]# ./message-2.pl  user1@s  'rech user2@s 22'
query=SELECT  id_cc_card FROM cc_callerid WHERE cid = 'user1@s' ;
card id found: 10 
we are in rech section
query=SELECT id_cc_card FROM cc_callerid WHERE cid = 'user2@s
'
```

There is no error. query1 is working fine but query2 is not working. I tried to use placeholders instead of `$share_reciver` but it is not working. I also tried with single quotes and without quotes. If I use `$calerid` instead of `$share_reciver` then it works fine. Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`placeholders and bound variables`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values) for your sql queries.  Never just put raw variables in your sql string:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{SELECT id_cc_card FROM cc_callerid WHERE cid=?})
$sth->execute($calerid) or die $dbh->errstr;
```

You'll have to adjust your initialization of `$calerid` to not have single quotes around it, as using placeholders takes care of that:

```
our $calerid = $ARGV[0];
```

Also, it should be sufficient to only connect to your database once.  You don't have to do it for each query.  Therefore, just put your connect statement at the beginning of the script.  You can even isolate all the constants the db connect relies on so that they aren't available later in your script:

```
our $dbh = do {
    my $database = "mya2billing";
    my $host = "localhost";
    my $port = "3306";
    my $user = "root";
    my $pass = "xxxxxx";
    my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=$database;host=$host;port=$port";

    DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pass) or die "DB connect failed: $DBI::errstr";
};
```

To reiterate, your second query should also use placeholders, like so:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id_cc_card FROM cc_callerid WHERE cid=?');
$sth->execute($share_reciver) or die $dbh->errstr;
```

Finally, it doesn't appear you're validating the returned content from external resources [`qx{}`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qx.html).  At the very least, I suspect that returned content might contain return characters you aren't expecting.  Therefore just whip out the [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html):

```
our $msg_arg2 = qx(echo $message | awk '{print \$2}');
chomp $msg_arg2;
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply i have also tried without and with quotes but not working   i think problum is   here when i try to pass 'rech user2@s 22'  and  our $msg_arg2 = qx(echo $message | awk '{print \$2}');
my $share_reciver =  "'$msg_arg2'"; after that query is not working  why   ?

Comment: query1 is working with both methods   but query2 is not working

Comment: query2 and query1 are identical.  You should use placeholders for query2 as well, just like I demonstrated here.

Comment: You make a good point about validating the results of external commands, but in this case there's no need for an external command at all. `qx(echo $message | awk '{print \$2}')` better written as `my $foo = (split ' ', $message, 3)[1]`

Comment: thanks a lot  mr   @ThisSuitIsBlackNot    your suggestion is works fine and after many days now my script is working  with this code    `my $foo = (split ' ', $message, 3)[1];`